# Servlet @Resource reading getInitParameters

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to read a context-param from my web.xml file into @Resource as:

```
@Resource(name=getServletContext().getInitParameter("DB_Name"))
private DataSource DB;
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>DB_Name</param-name>
    <param-value>samplename</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

But getting error **values for resource must be constants**. Is there a work-around to reading the param-name into @Resource without directly hard-coding it?

I've concluded this is impossible but not sure why: it's not good practice to hardcode the Database name in every servelt. I took out the @Resource and inserted this in the init() method, which is working.

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DB = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup(getServletContext().getInitParameter("DB_Name"));
```